# Is the associativity of vector addition a consequence of the others conditions in the definition of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to construct a quasi-vectorial space without an identity element?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24868/is-it-possible-to-construct-a-quasi-vectorial-space-without-an-identity-element)

I know that the commutativity of  vector addition is a consequence of the others conditions in the definition of a vector space. I do not think that the associativity of vector addition is a consequence of the others conditions (I am including the commutativity among them). How do I prove that? In fact, I do not even know what I should do.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: A ${\it vector\ space}$ is an additive group with some additional structure. An ${\it additive\ group}$ is a commutative group where the group operation is denoted by a $+$-sign. In any group the group operation is associative by definition. In short, in a vector space the addition is associative by definition.

Comment: See [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24868/is-it-possible-to-construct-a-quasi-vectorial-space-without-an-identity-element/24880#24880) for a discussion of the independence of the vector space axioms.

Comment: @Christian, I beleive the point of the question is, if something satisfies all the vector space axioms except possibly associativity of addition, can it be proved that in fact it does satisfy associativity of addition?

Comment: Commutativity only follows form the other axioms if the additive inverse axiom (equivalently, the cancellation axiom) is stated as holding *on both sides*. In most axiomatizations of vector spaces that I am familiar with in which the axioms of vector addition are stated explicitly (as opposed to simply saying "$(V,+)$ is an abelian group"), this is **not** the case: both the additive identity and additive inverse axioms are stated on a single side; if you do *that*, then commutative does *not* follow from the other axioms, as shown in the examples given in the post refered to above.