# An example of an incomplete vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to construct a quasi-vectorial space without an identity element?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24868/is-it-possible-to-construct-a-quasi-vectorial-space-without-an-identity-element)

I am looking for an example of a set and operations on this set that isn't quite a [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space).  As in it meets some of [the requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition),  but not all of them.

For example it could meet all of the definitions except [associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associativity) and therefore not a vector space.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/24880/742) for discussion of objects satisfying all except for one of the axioms of a vector space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invertible $n\times n$ matrices over some field will do it, I believe. Take the vectors to be $n \times n$ invertible matrices, but take vector addition to be matrix multiplication. It fails on two counts not one, though: 'addition' isn't commutative and scalar multiplication is not distributive.

Comment: There is in fact nothing special about matrices in this example. You can take *anything* that you can multiply by the same species of objects and scalars, and the same idea still works :) Ideas include:
* functions on some space $X$, possibly with some additional conditions, like continuous
* special classes of matrices: invertible, diagonal, ...

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in the notion of a module. A module is something that resembles a vector space in that you have addition and scalar multiplication. The gist is that instead of scalars in some vector field, you have a ring.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29